# How can I use a treetable to show all rows in an Oracle SQL table?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, treetable

I have this table:

CREATE TABLE perarea
  (
     id_area      INT primary key,
     nombre       VARCHAR2(200),
     id_areapadre INT references perarea(id_area)
  );

And this was added to access the data:

[image]

My intention is to create a hierarchy showing areas and their subordinates in the treeview. Then when a user clicks a node, have a table on the right of the treetable load all employee from that area.

First thing's first though, how can I populate the treetable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful to think of a [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) as a *view* of the underlying [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html). An example implementation of [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html), intended for use with [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), illustrates a hierarchical [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-) that may guide you. As you are using Oracle, you may find the article [*Dynamic JTree from database query*](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1380833?start=0) helpful, too.

Addendum: The article [*Understanding the TreeModel*](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/%7Ecs3283/ftp/Java/swingConnect/tech_topics/treemodel/treemodel.html) may be helpful, too.

Addendum: See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513) that uses `FileTreeModel`.