# How do I add a different JComboBox to each JTree node?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jtree

I have a JTree that I'm filling with skills for a Game Database programme that I'm writing.

There are several categories, and subcategories (actual skills), and then levels skill below that (sometimes). Currently I'm emulating this with one skill class, some options inside, and a few enums, plus a method to check that if the skill is a category (called isCategory). Two other things to note:

1. **Different types of skill behave differently.**
   Some are bought once, other several times, some have options to pick from etc
2. **Different categories contain different skill.**
    For instance The Weapon Skills category has different types of weapons, but the Armour Skills are in a different section.

I've seen a very good example of attaching a ComboBox via a cell renderer to each node in the tree. Here is the [example](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node156.html#SECTION000137000000000000000) I found.

I understand the above code, but I can't see how to would attach the combo box to a node, and not to the tree? I've read '[How to use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)', and I've run, and looked at the code for a few of the [demos for tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html). I can make basic trees, but I find the tutorials a bit obtuse and lacking in enough detail to figure out for myself how to proceed. I've found another [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatinganEditorJustforLeafNodes.htm) of only rendering leaf nodes as checkboxes, which is much more complex.

Obviously I'd like to combine the two, being able to have different categories able to have different skills and different skills have different levels of proficiency. However the only way I can think of doing so it to have different JComboBoxModels for the different types but I don't know how to do this, and I can't find out how. I've tried to edit the checkbox example to use ComboBoxes, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Could someone give me a hint as to what approach to take on this, as I'm new to Java and strugglingto figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) be a good place to start?

Conceptually, yes. Both `JTable` and `JTree` use the flyweight pattern to render and edit cells/nodes.

- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200937/230513) cites a basic `TreeCellRenderer`.
- This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513) illustrates a simple `TreeCellEditor` using the default renderer.
- This [example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692) shows an `Outline` view that incorporates features of both `JTable` and `JTree`.

[image]

Comment: These look great. I'll try and put something sensible together tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement `TreeCellRenderer` as well as `TreeCellEditor`. Both should return `JComboBox` with different model. Which model to choose you should decide in the `getTreeCellEditorComponent`/`getTreeCellRenderingComponent` depending on value parameter (the tree node in fact).

Comment: So Implement both of those in my skills class? How are they different? Could you expand on what you mean a little please?

Comment: It could be one class implementing both interfaces. In fact you need the 2 methods to get component for renderer and editor.

Comment: @Pureferret: This [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513) illustrates a `TreeCellEditor` using the default renderer.

Comment: @trashgod Am I thinking rightly that all I need to do is edit `getTreeCellEditorComponent` to return a different comboBox depending on checks I make, instead of `user` in your example? @Both how does `getTreeCellRenderingComponent` factor into this, just overloading the toString method? I.e. for a combo: `getSelected().getText()` (or something similar)? Is there a tutorial on this somewhere, the Java tutorials don't really seem to cover this in any great detail. Would [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) be a good place to start?