# Highlight the searched node in tree in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree, renderer, treemodel

```
m_searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = searchNode(m_searchText.getText());
        if (node != null) {
          TreeNode[] nodes = m_model.getPathToRoot(node);
          TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
          m_tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);
          m_tree.setSelectionPath(path);
        } else {
          System.out.println("Node with string " + m_searchText.getText() + " not found");
        }
    }
});
```

code for searchNode() is

```
public DefaultMutableTreeNode searchNode(String nodeStr) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null;
    Enumeration e = m_rootNode.breadthFirstEnumeration();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
      if (nodeStr.equals(node.getUserObject().toString())) {
        return node;
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have written this code top search a node in tree? But I'm having trouble highlighting the found node with a blue color. Can you provide a solution?

Comment: I've not tried this, but have you tried call `repaint` on the tree??

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean you "can't get that"? Doesn't `m_tree.repaint()` work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `TreeCellRenderer` can specify the desired color. See [*Customizing a Tree's Display*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display) and the examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802163/230513).