# Populate Jtree with Connect by

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing

I'm looking for a simple way to populate a jtree given a hierarchical scheme like: table (father,son). I was wondering if there is a quick way like when I populate a jlist or table just feeding it the query (in this particular case a Connect by is the query that gives me the structure and levels.) the depth is not fixated so I cannot use another structure. If this is not possible I'm looking for the easiest and fastest way.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3151493/230513).

Comment: do you know how to use treeModels? maybe DefaultTreeModel does provide you with good enough methods...